# [ros2] components registration from subdirectory CMakeLists file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that is separated into couple of subdirectories, each has its own CMakeLists.txt file that is included to the main CMakeLists.txt file by using add_subdirectory(). Each of these subdirectories contains the source code files for a different component that I want to use: e.g, I have a detection subdirectory, a tracking subdirectory and so forth. I am trying to register node components from within the subdirectories CMakeLists files by using rclcpp_components_register_nodes() but it seems as if the nodes don't get registered when I try to load them. Furthermore, they are not located at share/ament_index/resource_index/rclcpp_components/ like other components that I use.

If I take the contents of the subdirectories' CMakeLists.txt file to the main CMakeLists.txt and remove the call to add_subdirectory, everything works fine.

Anyone done something similar before?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361289/%5Bros2%5D-components-registration-from-subdirectory-cmakelists-file/) by [yardas](https://answers.ros.org/users/59239/yardas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If I take the contents of the subdirectories' CMakeLists.txt file to the main CMakeLists.txt and remove the call to add_subdirectory, everything works fine.

This is probably because in [CMake each call to `add_subdirectory()` creates a new scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891447/cmake-variable-scope-add-subdirectory), meaning CMake variables set in the subdirectory are not visible to the parent directory.

It looks like [`rclcpp_components_register_nodes()`calls`_rclcpp_components_register_package_hook`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7b2d983734ed186e5f05bfcabd8c0e80d43d83bb/rclcpp_components/cmake/rclcpp_components_register_node.cmake#L51)  This is [a macro that calls `ament_register_extension()`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7b2d983734ed186e5f05bfcabd8c0e80d43d83bb/rclcpp_components/rclcpp_components-extras.cmake.in#L18-L26). This [appends to the CMake variable `AMENT_EXTENSIONS_ament_package`](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/35c123889b3c397991c621e30453c797e26625aa/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_register_extension.cmake#L30-L33), presumably to register something to be called [when `ament_package()` is called](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/35c123889b3c397991c621e30453c797e26625aa/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake#L66). Since this is a subdirectory, the call to `ament_package()` in the parent directory doesn't see the changed value.

You might be able to work around this setting that variable in the `PARENT_SCOPE` at the very end of the `<subdirectory>/CMakeLists.txt`, though, it's possible other variables used by `rclcpp_components_register_nodes()` will need to be set in the parent scope too.

```
set(AMENT_EXTENSIONS_ament_package ${AMENT_EXTENSIONS_ament_package} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Alternatively, when a CMake project uses `add_subdirectory()` it might be a sign that it has gotten too big and should be split into smaller projects.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yardas](https://answers.ros.org/users/59239/yardas/) on 2020-09-13**:
Thank you for your response, yes what you're saying makes sense.
Currently the project is still quite small and well organized so I think that I'll just remove the add_subdirectory() and do everything on the main cmakelists file as you suggested.
Btw, do you know of any cmakelists style guide or something similar?

Thank you again :)

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-09-14**:
I'm afraid I don't know of any CMake style guides :( , though there is a package for linting CMake files: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/tree/master/ament_lint_cmake which seems to use a fork of https://github.com/richq/cmake-lint/